# Same primary keys for relation

Tags: sql, database, schema

Lets say I have two many-to-many relations called `Tutors` and `Assits`. They are both connected `courses`. If they are both inheritance of relation called `Staff` they both have the same primary keys. That would mean the many-to-many relation will also have the same primary keys.

If I have two relations with the same primary keys what do I do? Here is an example of the table:

[image]

Comment: `Course` will have two foreign keys: `tutor_id` and `assistant_id`. What's the problem? They will be clearly identified.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm trying to write down the schema in 3NF. But assists and tutors relation have the same primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple to add those two relationships. For example:

```
create table staff (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20)
);

create table tutor (
  id int primary key not null,
  office_number varchar(10),
  foreign key (id) references staff (id)
);

create table assistant (
  id int primary key not null,
  title varchar(20),
  foreign key (id) references staff (id)
);

create table course (
  course_id int not null,
  year int not null,
  semester int not null,
  primary key (course_id, year, semester),
  tutor_id int not null references tutor (id),
  assistant_id int not null references assistant (id)
);
```

Now, if you insert some data:

```
insert into staff (id, name) values (1, 'Alice');
insert into staff (id, name) values (2, 'Victor');

insert into tutor (id, office_number) values (1, '101-A');
insert into assistant (id, title) values (2, 'Adjunct Professor');

insert into course (course_id, year, semester, tutor_id, assistant_id) 
  values (101, 2020, 1, 1, 2);
```

You can run a query over it:

```
select 
  c.course_id, c.year, c.semester,
  ts.name as tutor, t.office_number,
  ta.name as assistant, a.title
from course c
join tutor t on c.tutor_id = t.id
join staff ts on ts.id = t.id
join assistant a on c.assistant_id = a.id
join staff ta on ta.id = a.id
```

Result:

```
course_id  year  semester  tutor  office_number  assistant  title             
---------- ----- --------- ------ -------------- ---------- ----------------- 
101        2020  1         Alice  101-A          Victor     Adjunct Professor
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dAswFYM6fTLSLMbg5fXC7o/0).

Comment: But each course can have multiple tutors and assistants. won't putting them on course cause same primary keys repeat in course?

Answer (score 0):

If the relation course - tutor is a many-to-many relation you will need an extra xref table:

```
course -|---|< course_tutor >0---|- tutor
```

The same thing for `assistant`.

Even when the same person is tutor and assistant in the same course there will be a record in `course_tutor` and `course_assistant` with the same `course_id` and `staff_id` but that is not a problem.